# Set builder notation for matching element pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, multisets

I have a set of pairs, $S = \{ \langle a,b \rangle_1, \langle a,b \rangle_2, ..., \langle a,b \rangle_n \} $ where $a$ is not unique amongst the pairs.

If I want to express the extraction of all the instances of $b$ for a particular instance of $a$, as a function, lets say $groupPairs()$. Is the following correct?

$groupPairs(a) = \{ b | \langle a, b \rangle \in S \}$

What if the actual pairs were not unique, and $S$ is a list rather than a set? How would I express the same function (thus giving me a non-unique list of instances of $b$)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with set builder notation, but perhaps you could write (clumsily) $\{(b,n) | (a,b) \in S, n = | \{ b | (a,b) \in S \}| \}$. This is not a list, but the second element gives the number of times the first element appears.

Comment: Note that set membership implies items appear at most once, so in the present context the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ will not repeat (even if the first coordinate $a$ does happen to repeat).  To get repetitions of the ordered pairs you need what is called a *multi-set* or (in many programming contexts) a *bag*.

Comment: @hardmath Yes. Thats why I said $S$ becomes a list and not a set, you can see it as a sequence. But I don't know if there is any elegant mathematical notation to iterate through and extract the list (or bag or whatever) of $b$ items.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't want to count the number of times. I want a list of the actual elements. Imagine it is a pair of 'surname' and 'name' and we're extracting the list of 'names' with the same 'surname'.

Comment: Okay, the *list* allows repetitions but also arranges an order of items (sequence) that you seem not to want  (it wouldn't make a difference if *all* items were the same, though).

Comment: Are you collecting the pairs or the 'b' part? If the latter, then there is no difference between the last elements of (joe, murphy) and (tony,murphy).

Comment: @hardmath Well in my particular case order does not matter (although it would be useful to learn how to do it with a sequence too I guess :) ). So yes the correct definition is a bag or multi-set.

Comment: @copper.hat In my particular case I am collecting the 'b' part. (In reality they are numbers that I will need to sum over with $\sum$ but as such it is unrelated to this problem.) To use the surname and name example, the pairs are ('murphy', 'joe') and ('murphy', 'tony') and I want ('joe', 'tony'). In the case $S$ is not a set but a bag, if there happens to be ('murphy', 'joe'),('murphy', 'joe'),('murphy', 'tony') I want ('joe','joe','tony').

Comment: Then this is essentially the same as gettting back (('joe',2), ('tony,1)), which is what I have in my first comment. I mean, there is no distinction between 'joe' and 'joe'.

Comment: @copper.hat I get it now... but if $S$ is not a set, the set builder notation is not applicable I guess. What would you use instead, if $S$ was a multi-set?

Comment: Think of a multi set as a function from the set (or some suitable universal set) to the non negative integers. (An ordinary set can be thought of as a function to $\{0,1\}$.) Then what I wrote above is essentially a multi set. The set builder notation is adequate, but a little cumbersome. Just like defining ordered pairs is cumbersome.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. Is there any other (less cumbersome) notation I could use?

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) often means avoiding any explicit enumeration of the items (up to repetition, somehow, in the case of multi-sets) by giving a predicate that characterizes those items which belong.  Strictly speaking this cannot work for multi-sets, since a predicate is either satisfied or not (true or false) upon application to an item.

What would be needed is a function, just as @copper.hat proposed, that assigns a count to each member of the underlying set.  Once one has gone out on the limb, one may as well let the function itself be the representation of the multi-set.

There is a way to make the explicit enumeration of items in a *list* a faithful representation of a multi-set, i.e. one that disallows variable arrangement of the items.  This is simply to insist on a *sorted list*.  This requires the underlying set (domain) to have a sort order that is canonical or at least understood from the context.  For surnames one might make the obvious choice of *lexicographic* ordering.

In the end what makes the best choice of representation depends on the use to which the notation is being put.  An author needs their readers to be able to parse the notation with minimum confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think the multiset union symbol $\uplus$ is clear and popular enough to use on its own? Or would I need to write a sentence or even define it (that it adds the sum together).

Comment: I think any choice of notation for multi-sets will need a definition in your write-up; there are no choices that are accepted by consensus, analogous to curly brackets $\{\ldots\}$ or union $\cup$ for sets.  But definitions are good -- they give the Readers a chance to realize they are not in Kansas anymore!